# Gmaps4Rails - How to refresh clusters?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I have an coffeescript function responsible for hiding/showing markers based on category passed as argument. `Gmaps.markers` variable has all markers loaded on map.

```
@displayMarkers = (category) ->
  i = 0
  while i < Gmaps.markers.length
    if Gmaps.markers[i].category is category
      Gmaps.markers[i].serviceObject.setVisible(true)
    else
      Gmaps.markers[i].serviceObject.setVisible(false)
    i++
```

How could I invoke `MarkerClusterer.repaint()` via JS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the methods in gmaps4rails handle this by default when you add/remove:

```
var marker = handler.addMarker(json);
handler.removeMarker(marker)
```

So I'd advise you to use them or to [check their code](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/objects/handler.coffee)